# CTreeCtrl Custom Draw for additional States

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, treeview, visual-c++-6

My need is to have about 30 states fro the Tree Items and as per the limitation CTreeCtrl will not support not more than 15 States.

From lots of stackoverflow browsing I found that I need to write a Custom Draw on the Custom CTreeCtrl.

Can anyone suggest me a good link/demo code for implementing the Custom Draw for the additional States.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Codeproject has a bunch of code about this.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/325/A-custom-drawn-TreeList-Control

States are not everything: It depends on how may symbols you need...
Merge states and symbols into the needed permutations.

You can create your own CImageList and use drawing icons to create the mixed symbols.